# How to replace the missing data from AMELIA results

Tags: missing-data

I have run a AMELIA imputation for a data set including missing data. I need to replace the missing points by the result of    amelia().    But it content 5 group of imputed values. How can i choose the best one to replace the missing values (to plot a graph of data set after imputing)

Answer (score 0):

You use all 5.

You have to perform whatever you wanted to do with the data on all 5 sets of data and then combine the results of that.

i.e. you run a t-test on all 5 datasets and then combine the results..somehow.. I have not yet looked into that, but from what I have heared you can use the zelig R package to do it somewhat easily. I also noted a reference to papers that should describe methods to combine those, but have not looked into that either:  King et al. (2001) and Schafer (1997).

My guess is that you just average out the p-values gained from the analysis?